# Enabling core data lightweight migration in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

According to the articles I have read the correct way to enable core data light weight migrations is by passing options to `addPersistentStoreWithType`:

```
let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]

try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(
NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
```

But in my `Xcode 8` `Swift 3` project I can't find where `addPersistentStoreWithType` is called. This is the only `core data` code that was generated when I created my project:

```
 // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Habits")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

**How do I enable lightweight migrations in Xcode 8 using Swift 3?**

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? None of the answers provided as of JAN 20, 2018 seem to work.

Comment: @DavidVincentGagne  -  I cannot get any of the answers to work either. Any luck?

Comment: @Nick My problem ended up being unrelated. Sorry.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You do it using `NSPersistentStoreDescription`, which is where all those options moved to in the Swift 3 updates. Do this before the call to `loadPersistentStores`:

```
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
```

Comment: do we leave the line

fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")

unchanged like that?

Comment: my app  crashing when i add this code. is anything else should i do ?

Comment: You should ask a question that describes your problem, because "my app is crashing" is too vague to get a useful answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860308/core-data-lightweight-migration-in-swift-3-not-working my question.

Comment: after adding this line of codes, I did not get any data from coredata. So how can i get my save data?

Comment: My guess is that @balkaran singh meant to say that Xcode is crashing and not the iOS app he's developing. That's what's happening to me, too. I have the exact same problem as the original question posted. Making the changes you suggested simply causes Xcode to crash.

Comment: Why we need to set that, if ```shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically``` and ```shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically``` are ```true``` by default?

Comment: By default it is true only then why need to do it.

Comment: By default it is true only then why need to do it and by assigning this you are rewriting all the default descriptions. Because of that the data will be lost whenever the persistent coordinator loads.

Comment: As per apple's documentation for ```shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically``` and ```shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically``` the default value for them is set to true, so am not very sure why everyone is suggesting to set them to true? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @NSDumb Only the fact that you're responding to an answer from nearly four years ago and that the frameworks change over time.

Comment: This will make all data to be lost everytime the app is restarted (persistent coordinator loads).

Comment: @DaronTancharoen That is not correct. Core Data is able to migrate data to new model versions without losing the data.

Answer (score 9):

Note that both `NSPersistentStore`'s `shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically` and `shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically` are `true` by default.

Apple reference for:

- [shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640623-shouldinfermappingmodelautomatic)
- [shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nspersistentstoredescription/1640566-shouldmigratestoreautomatically)

Answer (score 8):

You can just start a new project in Xcode 7, and copy and paste the generated core data code to the new new project!

I created a project in Xcode 7 and migrated it to Xcode 8, this is the generated code. (I have already added the two options for enabling lightweight stack migration)

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: URL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.MyApp" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data" as AnyObject?
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason as AnyObject?

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

You can just copy the above and paste it in your App Delegate.

One thing to note is that please edit this line so that it gets your data model's URL:

```
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MyApp", withExtension: "momd")!
```

Answer (score 7):

With the new `NSPersistentContainer` there are many sensible defaults. You don't have to set the properties, which most of the answers give.

Simply create the container and load.

```
let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: dataModelName)
container.loadPersistentStores { storeDescription, error in
    // You may verify the default storeDescription has the right default for light migration
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I make append to new description instead of replacement

```
let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
container.persistentStoreDescriptions.append(description)
```

Comment: Good point! Replacing it altogether like the accepted answer seemed to lose all the old data in my case and as soon as I used append they came back.

Comment: Awesome. You saved me!

Comment: Thanks, You saved. Small heads-up Don't assign like this `container.persistentStoreDescriptions = description`