# Xcode: +CoreDataProperties.swift issue

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, image, ipad

I'm designing an app which is going well but I had an issue a while ago whereby I had to create a new model for CoreData because I made alterations to the Entities. I'm up to the fourth version and I had another issue with the app and I cleaned it. Now, this is what I'm getting:

The 'deleted' Attribute is set to NSDate

[image: Image 1]

but after I try to build it again I get the following error:

[image: Error Image]

I thought if I made alterations to the Entity Xcode would pick that up and alter any files accordingly! But that doesn't seem to be the case!

I've tried deleting the +CoreDataProperties.swift files and the 'Shopping List' swift file, recreating the 'Shopping List' swift file, under a different class name, and trying to build it again but I get the same error. This tells me its a CoreData issue, not a Swift issue. Obviously I need the attribute as NSDate but I'm not sure where to go from here!

The only way I can get the app to build is to comment out the 'deleted' attribute in the +CoreDataProperties.swift file and it runs fine.

I have the app running on a test iPhone 6 and the last time I made changes to the Entity I lost all the data I entered manually on the phone because of errors. The only way to get the app back up and running was to delete the app off the phone and reinstall it. I seriously don't want to go down that route again because I have nearly 450 various records on the phone.

If I leave the 'deleted' Attribute commented out when its uploaded to the app store, will it fail to upload, and will it fail to work correctly if the upload is successful?

I'd rather sort the issue before trying!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is called light weight migrations. In app delegate you need to tell the app to look for the new version and create presistence store

```
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.




    */// THIS IS THE CODE YOU NEED TO ADD
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NAMEGOESHERE")
       let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()

       description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
       description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
// End of new code

 container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
```

This method worked for me. There are a number of tutorials out there on doing light weight migrations [here](https://cocoacasts.com/migrating-a-data-model-with-core-data/) and there is a stack overflow answer which is one I actually referred to when I had this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851950/enabling-core-data-lightweight-migration-in-swift-3). By doing migrations your app shall be able to create a new persistance store and in that new store it ll change the attribute of deleted from Bool to NSdate as in the generated managedobject file. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Ali, I'll give it a go. Thanks for the speedy reply by the way, much appreciated.